# Response headers in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, web.config contains headers for Content-Security-Policy in httpProtocol->customHeaders.
For the certain page, I needed to have CSP with different value. I added following code in action method of controller class.

```
 Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Security-Policy");
 Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
 return View();
```

After loading the page in Chrome, using the Developer tools , I observed that there are two CSP headers. One is from newly added CSP while other from the web.config.
I wanted to know when the header from web.config is inserted. My requirement is to get rid of the header from the web.config for this web page. I am using Razor page.

Comment: I have no personal experience, but I believe that the [NWebsec nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec) has support for this. It allows to set CSP through Attributes at Controller level, and even at Action-method level, instead of globally in web.config. See the examples at this link: https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/Configuring-csp.html#configuring-csp-through-mvc-attributes